# No process on the other end of the pipe. Error after restoring DB

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am restoring my DB from a stored procedure from my web app. To accomplish this I set the DB to single user mode then restore with REPLACE so that it overwrites the current DB. After the restore I set back to multi_user mode. Everything appears to work fine until I navigate to another page which runs a query producting this error. I have tried everything from [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/) blog post that everyone is linking to for this error. After I click to another page and then back to that page again the error goes away. Any ideas what's going on here?

A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) Type: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider Stack: at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WriteSni() at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ExecuteFlush() at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteRPC(_SqlRPC[] rpcArray, Int32 timeout, Boolean inSchema, SqlNotificationRequest notificationRequest, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isCommandProc) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader

Comment: You might wnt to disable shared memory and use only TCP/IP or pipes

Comment: @ErstwhileIII thanks for the suggestion, tried that but got the same result

Comment: Same result? "shared Memory provider" complaint?  Not sure how you could get a complaint if shared memory is turned off .. but then I am not where you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that a pooled connection got killed and the error was returned when an attempt was made to reuse a broken one.  Try invoking SqlConnection.ClearPool after the restore.

Comment: thank you this seemed to do the trick: SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()